sin approximation using gram schmidt and maxima
I'm trying to reproduce the sin(x) approximation example from "Linear algebra done right" using Maxima, but I get weird results. Here is my code:
load("eigen");
ip (f, g) := integrate (f * g, u, a, b);
basis: makelist (u^k, k, 0, 5);
e: gramschmidt (basis, ip), a=-%pi, b=%pi;
sl: makelist (sin(u), x, 1, 6);
re: map(ip, sl, e)*e, a=-%pi, b=%pi;
expand(float(apply("+", re)));

which gives me 4.867477078388566*u^5 - 66.27194960446585*u^3 + 195.5285758118965*u
while the correct result is 0.987862*x − 0.155271*x^3 + 0.00564312*x^5
What am I doing wrong?

First thing that comes to mind is that perhaps there is a normalization which is omitted. You might consider sending a message to the maxima-discuss mailing list to get more eyes on it. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

By the way, the value of _ is the immediately preceding input, while % is the immediately preceding output. It might not change anything, but anyway I'll suggest replacing _ by % in the fifth line.

I changed _ to x. The results is still the same.

Yeah, looks like makelist treats _ as an ordinary dummy variable.

Looks like you need to normalize the basis before applying it to sin(u). Here's how I phrased it; no doubt there are other ways to say it.
(%i2) load("eigen") $

(%i3) ip (f, g) := integrate (f * g, u, -%pi, %pi) $

(%i4) n: 5 $

(%i5) basis: makelist (u^k, k, 0, n);
                             2   3   4   5
(%o5)                [1, u, u , u , u , u ]
(%i6) e: gramschmidt (basis, ip);
                2      2        2        2
             3 u  - %pi   u (5 u  - 3 %pi )
(%o6) [1, u, ───────────, ─────────────────, 
                  3               5
       4         2  2        4         4         2  2         4
   35 u  - 30 %pi  u  + 3 %pi   u (63 u  - 70 %pi  u  + 15 %pi )
   ───────────────────────────, ────────────────────────────────]
               35                              63

Find normalizing factors z and use them to construct an orthonormal basis.
(%i7) z: map (lambda ([ee], ip (ee, ee)), e);
                   3       5       7         9         11
              2 %pi   8 %pi   8 %pi   128 %pi   128 %pi
(%o7) [2 %pi, ──────, ──────, ──────, ────────, ─────────]
                3       45     175     11025      43659
(%i8) e1: e / sqrt(z);
                                                      2      2
               1            sqrt(3) u     sqrt(5) (3 u  - %pi )
(%o8) [─────────────────, ──────────────, ─────────────────────, 
       sqrt(2) sqrt(%pi)             3/2        3/2    5/2
                          sqrt(2) %pi          2    %pi
              2        2          4         2  2        4
sqrt(7) u (5 u  - 3 %pi )  3 (35 u  - 30 %pi  u  + 3 %pi )
─────────────────────────, ───────────────────────────────, 
        3/2    7/2                    7/2    9/2
       2    %pi                      2    %pi
                4         2  2         4
sqrt(11) u (63 u  - 70 %pi  u  + 15 %pi )
─────────────────────────────────────────]
               7/2    11/2
              2    %pi

Verify that e1 is an orthonormal basis.
(%i9) genmatrix (lambda ([i, j], ip (e1[i], e1[j])), n + 1, n + 1);
                      ┌                  ┐
                      │ 1  0  0  0  0  0 │
                      │                  │
                      │ 0  1  0  0  0  0 │
                      │                  │
                      │ 0  0  1  0  0  0 │
(%o9)                 │                  │
                      │ 0  0  0  1  0  0 │
                      │                  │
                      │ 0  0  0  0  1  0 │
                      │                  │
                      │ 0  0  0  0  0  1 │
                      └                  ┘

Now use the basis to construct an approximation to sin(u).
(%i10) coeffs: map (lambda ([ee], ip (sin(u), ee)), e1);
                                             3
           sqrt(2) sqrt(3)     sqrt(7) (4 %pi  - 60 %pi)
(%o10) [0, ───────────────, 0, ─────────────────────────, 0, 
              sqrt(%pi)                3/2    7/2
                                      2    %pi
                                      5           3
                      sqrt(11) (16 %pi  - 1680 %pi  + 15120 %pi)
                      ──────────────────────────────────────────]
                                      7/2    11/2
                                     2    %pi
(%i11) approx: coeffs . e1;
                  5           3
(%o11) (11 (16 %pi  - 1680 %pi  + 15120 %pi) u
      4         2  2         4           11
 (63 u  - 70 %pi  u  + 15 %pi ))/(128 %pi  )
           3                 2        2
   7 (4 %pi  - 60 %pi) u (5 u  - 3 %pi )   3 u
 + ───────────────────────────────────── + ────
                       7                      2
                  8 %pi                    %pi
(%i12) expand (approx);
            5          5           5        3          3
       693 u    72765 u    654885 u    315 u    39375 u
(%o12) ────── - ──────── + ───────── - ────── + ────────
            6         8          10         4         6
       8 %pi     8 %pi      8 %pi      4 %pi     4 %pi
                                  3
                          363825 u    105 u    16065 u   155925 u
                        - ───────── + ────── - ─────── + ────────
                                8          2        4          6
                           4 %pi      8 %pi    8 %pi      8 %pi
(%i13) fpprintprec: 6;
(%o13)                          6
(%i14) float (expand (approx));
                        5             3
(%o14)      0.00564312 u  - 0.155271 u  + 0.987862 u

